# Invalid Syntax: adding 10 to input

Tags: python

I've been doing some python(using spyder) and being **completely new** to all of this, I'm pretty confused. My friend typed this code:

```
elif x== '3' :
  number = input('Enter an integer \n')
  try:
     the sum = int(float(number)+(float(10))
     print(number + 'plus 10 equals'+ the sum)
```

And it works for her, but not me, when I type the exact same thing, and same indents and all. There is a cross on the side(code analysis) that appears on the line that starts with 'the sum'. Apparently, there's invalid syntax. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get `the sum` from? That is not valid syntax, and I should not have worked for your friend either. Maybe you meant `the_sum` _note the underscore._

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this line by line..

```
elif x== '3' :
```

Should be:

```
if x == '3':
```

You should start if statements with `if` instead of `elif`. Also, make sure `x` has a value earlier in your code.

---

If you're brand new, I would wait just a little longer to add `try:` statements. But I'll include it in the final answer.

---

```
the sum = int(float(number)+(float(10))
```

Should be:

```
the_sum = float(number) + 10
```

Use a `float` if you expect `number` to have a decimal. Based on the info you provided, there isn't a need to convert the `float` back to an `int` which is what you're doing when you call `int(float(...`

Note that a space in a variable name is not valid syntax. Adding an underscore makes `the_sum` valid.

---

```
print(number + 'plus 10 equals'+ the sum)
```

Python2 and Python3 have different options for formatting output. More info [here](https://pyformat.info/). I'll use Python2, so your code should be:

```
print ('%f plus 10 equals %f' % (number, the_sum))
```

`%f` means format a variable as a float. The first `%f` will be replaced with `number` and the second with `the_sum`.

---

All together you have:

```
if x == '3':
  number = input('Enter an integer \n')
  try:
    the_sum = float(number) + 10
    print ('%f plus 10 equals %f' % (number, the_sum))
  except:
    pass
```

**Bonus:** Does your script break when you enter a character? How could you use the `try:` statement to improve?